# I'm not able to launch "monitor.bat" (Android Device Monitor) due to Java problems

Tags: java, android, debugging, monitor, unreal-engine4

I need the Android Device Monitor to understand why my Android app is crashing. The problem is that everytime that I try to launch it, I got this error:

"An error has occured. See the log file. C:/..pathname../.log."

And this is that log: http://pastebin.com/dJ7uYSAu

I tried to install newer and older version of JAVA. x32 and x64bit. No idea what's wrong with that Monitor.

PS= I installed "Android Works 1R1", from Unreal Engine.